# How to get rid of the warning with time.h in C++?

Tags: c++, warnings, system-calls, time.h

When I use this

```
#include<time.h>
//...
int n = time(0);
//...
```

I get a warning about converting time to int.  Is there a way to remove this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time returns `time_t` and not integer. Use that type preferably because it may be larger than `int`.

If you really need `int`, then typecast it explicitly, for example:

```
int n = (int)time(0);
```

Comment: If your program is gonna work until 2038 you got a problem ;)

Comment: Though technically the correct answer to the question. This is not a good idea. Better to convert your code to use time_t

Comment: This treats the symptoms and not the illness.

Comment: Hey, just read the answer. I said "use that type preferably".

Comment: As well as the size issue, `time_t` is permitted by POSIX to be a floating-point type, not any size of integer.

Answer (score 20):

[Yes, change n to be a `time_t`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_t).  If you look at the signature in time.h on most / all systems, you'll see that that's what it returns.

```
#include<time.h>
//...
time_t n = time(0);
//...
```

Note that [Arak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127893/arak) is right: using a 32 bit int is a problem, at a minimum, [due to the 2038 bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).  However, you should consider that any sort of arithmetic on an integer n (rather than a time_t) only increases the probability that your code will trip over that bug early.

*PS: In case I didn't make it clear in the original answer, the best response to a compiler warning is almost always to address the situation that you're being warned about.  For example, forcing higher precision data into a lower precision variable loses information - the compiler is trying to warn you that you might have just created a landmine bug that someone won't trip over until much later.*

Comment: @AraK, saw your comment above and you made a good point about 2038.

Comment: Maybe using `auto` even better.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using Visual C++. The return type of `time(0)` is `64bit int` even if you are programming for `32bit` platform unlike `g++`. To remove the warning, just assign `time(0)` to `64bit` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a type of time_t instead of an int.

See the example at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_t.

Answer (score -2):

The reason is time() functions returns a time_t time so you might need to do a static cast to an int or uint in this case. Write in this way:

```
time_t timer;
int n = static_cast<int> (time(&timer)); // this will give you current time as an integer and it is same as time(NULL)
```